# MySQL - Exclude Most Recent Month by Group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery

**Problem:**

The Employee table holds the salary information in a year.

Write a SQL to get the cumulative sum of an employee's salary over a period of 3 months but exclude the most recent month.

The result should be displayed by 'Id' ascending, and then by 'Month' descending.

**Employee table:**

```
| Id | Month | Salary |
|----|-------|--------|
| 1  | 1     | 20     |
| 2  | 1     | 20     |
| 1  | 2     | 30     |
| 2  | 2     | 30     |
| 3  | 2     | 40     |
| 1  | 3     | 40     |
| 3  | 3     | 60     |
| 1  | 4     | 60     |
| 3  | 4     | 70     |
```

**My Code:**

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.Month, 
  (SELECT SUM(Salary) 
   FROM  Employee AS t2
   WHERE t1.Id = t2.Id
   AND   t1.Month >= t2.Month) AS Salary
FROM Employee t1
WHERE Month <> (SELECT 
            MAX(Month) 
            FROM Employee
            GROUP BY t1.Id)
ORDER BY Id, Month DESC;
```

**My Output:**

```
| Id | Month | Salary |
|----|-------|--------|
| 1  | 3     | 90     |
| 1  | 2     | 50     |
| 1  | 1     | 20     |
| 2  | 2     | 50     |
| 2  | 1     | 20     |
| 3  | 3     | 100    |
| 3  | 2     | 40     |
```

**Expected:**

```
| Id | Month | Salary |
|----|-------|--------|
| 1  | 3     | 90     |
| 1  | 2     | 50     |
| 1  | 1     | 20     |
| 2  | 1     | 20     |
| 3  | 3     | 100    |
| 3  | 2     | 40     |
```

I used **MAX()** and **GROUP BY()** functions to exclude the most recent month of each group, but it doesn't work for Id=2.

Is there any advice on how to get rid of the following row?

```
| 2  | 2     | 50     |
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nearly, but see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: why are `month = 4` rows excluded from the result?

Comment: @vkp Because the problem wants to exclude the most recent months of each employee Id. For __Id = 1, 3__, the most recent __month = 4__, but for __Id = 2__, the most recent __month = 2__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this answer is closest to what you were trying to do in your original query:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.month,
    (SELECT SUM(salary)
       FROM employee t2
      WHERE t1.id = t2.id
        AND t1.month >= t2.month
        AND t1.month - t2.month < 3) AS salary
  FROM employee t1
 WHERE month <> (SELECT MAX(month)
                   FROM employee t3
                  WHERE t3.id = t1.id)
 ORDER by id, month desc;
```

On second look you were actually pretty close.  I believe the problem was that the "GROUP BY t1.Id" line doesn't actually group anything because t1.Id is constant for any given subquery as "t1" is defined in the outtermost select statement.  Replace it with a where clause and limit the total to 3 months in the SUM() query, and you're there.

Comment: It helps a lot! I guess __WHERE__ clause sometimes can work as __GROUP BY__, which is the same idea for the subquery in the __SELECT__ statement in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.month,
    (SELECT SUM(salary)
       FROM employee t2
      WHERE t1.id = t2.id
        AND t1.month >= t2.month
        AND t1.month - t2.month < 3) AS salary
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM employee p
     WHERE month <> (select MAX(month)
      FROM employee c where c.id = p.id)) t1
ORDER BY id, month desc;
```

Output is:

```
+------+-------+--------+
| id   | month | salary |
+------+-------+--------+
|    1 |     3 |     90 |
|    1 |     2 |     50 |
|    1 |     1 |     20 |
|    2 |     1 |     20 |
|    3 |     3 |    100 |
|    3 |     2 |     40 |
+------+-------+--------+
```

The problem you were having was that you were deleting only the last month present across all employees.  What I believe you wanted was to delete the last month present for each employee even if that last month was several months back.  This solution creates a derived table where the last month is missing for each employee and uses that in place of your t1 employee table.

Comment: Updated to limit the sum to 3 months.

Answer (score 2):

To only get the cumulative sum for the last 3 months, excluding the most recent month per id, you can use

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.Month, SUM(t2.Salary) 
FROM Employee t1
JOIN Employee t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id AND t1.Month - t2.Month <= 2 AND t1.Month - t2.Month >= 0
JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(month) as max_mth from Employee GROUP BY id) tmax on tmax.id=t1.id AND tmax.max_mth<>t1.month
GROUP BY t1.Id, t1.Month
ORDER BY t1.Id, t1.Month DESC;
```

Comment: Nice job reading the full question including the part about 3 months.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But could you explain a little bit more - why my original code doesn't work out? I've never used __AND__ inside a __JOIN__ clause - not sure if there's a reference site?

Comment: @YunZhou I believe the underlying problem is your line "GROUP BY t1.Id" doesn't really do anything because it's an attribute defined outside of the nested subquery.  However, it doesn't throw an error because t1.id is constant for the given subquery.

Comment: @YunZhou - See my second answer.  I think you were actually very close in your original post.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT e.Id, e.Month, SUM( e2.Salary ) AS 'Salary'

FROM 
    Employee AS e

    INNER JOIN Employee AS e2
        ON e2.Id = e.Id
        AND e2.Month <= e.Month

WHERE 
    e.Month <> ( SELECT MAX( [Month] ) FROM Employee WHERE Id = e.Id )

GROUP BY
    e.Id, e.Month

ORDER BY 
    e.Id, e.Month DESC
```

Output is:

```
+----+-------+--------+
| Id | Month | Salary |
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 |     3 |     90 |
|  1 |     2 |     50 |
|  1 |     1 |     20 |
|  2 |     1 |     20 |
|  3 |     3 |    100 |
|  3 |     2 |     40 |
+----+-------+--------+
```